# returning from procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database of english language words, i want to make a procedure in mysql, the input argument of procedure is a word. the purpose of procedure is to take first alphabet of the given input word and return all the words staring from that alphabet. 
for example:
call new_procedure('action',@total);
this command should return me all the words from my database which are starting from 'a'. 
i have written the following code but it is returning zero rows :( 
help me i am new at mysql

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`(in error_word varchar(30),
out total varchar(50))
BEGIN
declare xx varchar(2);
set xx = substring('error_word',1,1);
select word from words
where word like 'xx%'
into total;
END
```

Comment: You can't put the `xx` inside quotes, because then it's treated as the literal string 'xx', not as the variable named xx. You need to use `CONCAT(xx, '%')`

Comment: yes thankyou concat command is working. but i think there is some problem in returning the output. i am expecting to get at least 1000 rows back, but geting empty row :(

Comment: If you want a result set back from a MySQL procedure, just do the SELECT, don't use `INTO total`. Then fetch from the `CALL` query in your app, like you would from a SELECT. The procedure will have a result set.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code to find/return a specific word in your table and that will tell you if the basic syntax of your procedure is correct.

Example... ask it to search the table for a record containing the word 'action' and return the results...

In other words comment out the code that attempts to set xx = to the first character of the argument... and modify your code to simply use the entire argument in the query.

Then you know the procedure and the query are working.

Then start to review your syntax for parsing the argument and getting it into your variable.

Been a long time since I've done MySQL but I thought I would take a shot at suggesting a trouble shooting technique. Hope I explained it properly.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`(in error_word varchar(30),
out total varchar(50))
BEGIN

select word from words
where word LIKE '%' + @error_word + '%'
into total;
END
```